# Planned Maintenance scheduled for Tuesday, September 29, 2020 for Data Explorer

Tags: discussion, data-explorer, announcements

> **Update: The maintenance went as planned.**

---

**tl;dr;** Planned service interruption that will impact Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE). The site will be inaccessible for up to 12 hours on September 29, 2020 starting at 2:00pm UTC.

### Short Version:

There will be an extended service outage for up to 12 hours starting at 2pm UTC (10am US/Eastern) on September 29, 2020. During this time only the Stack Exchange Data Explorer will be inaccessible. This maintenance will not impact Stack Overflow, the Stack Exchange sites, Jobs, Chat, Teams, or any Enterprise cloud hosted instances.

### Longer Version

#### What we'll be doing

The SQL Server for Data Explorer is getting new SSDs. We will be replacing the current array with some  shiny new drives. The plan for tomorrow will be:

- Taking SEDE offline for maintenance
- Robocopying all the files from the current array to somewhere else for safe keeping
- Installing the new array
- Robocopying all the files back to the new array
- Start SQL Server
- Hope everything works
- If not, then I'll be refreshing the databases like we typically do during the weekly refresh.

We're not expecting any issues, and the outage shouldn't be as long as I've listed, but I'm purposely baking in extra time, in the event we need refresh the databases.

### Questions or concerns?

Please post a comment or answer below; I'll do my best to address any concerns between now and the maintenance window.

Comment: If you don't mind sharing, which model of SSDs are being used?

Comment: @SonictheMaskedWerehog They should be Micron 5300 PRO 7.68 TB SATA drives

Comment: Are the 5300 and 7300 series the same price: (one example): https://m.cdw.com/product/micron-5300-pro-solid-state-drive-7.68-tb-sata-6gb-s/5813378 vs https://www.cdw.com/product/Micron-7300-PRO-solid-state-drive-7.68-TB-U.2-PCIe-3.0-x4-NVMe/6099354 - yet much faster.

Comment: Consider adding status-completed @Taryn?

Comment: @Rob Yep, but that machine doesn't have U.2 slots for NVMe drives, so we're limited by SATA in this case. Not ideal, but that's the setup. In other machines we are using the NVMe drives, up in the 15TB variety :)

Comment: @Taryn isn't this supposed to be marked [tag:status-completed], if the maintenance went well?